# SwiftUI / iOS 13 - NotificationCenter with Multiple Scenes

Tags: ipad, swiftui, nsnotificationcenter

With the introduction of iOS 13, a single app can have multiple scenes. In particular, on the iPad, you can run 2 scenes of an app side by side.

This creates a problem in my app with `NotificationCenter`. A `NotificationCenter` event is shared by across all scenes. While this could be useful syncing data across scenes, some events that are intended to be responded within the original scene are handled by all 2 scenes.

For example, in this custom `UIHostingController` class, I have a function to handle `UIKeyCommands` and post a `Notification` to the `NotificationCenter`.

```
class HostingController: UIHostingController<ContentView> {
    override var keyCommands: [UIKeyCommand]? {
        var result: [UIKeyCommand] = [
        UIKeyCommand(
                title: "New File",
                action: #selector(handleNotification),
                input: "N",
                modifierFlags: [.command],
                discoverabilityTitle: "New File"
            )
        ]
    }

    @objc func handleNotification(sender: UIKeyCommand){
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name.handleKeyboardShortcut, object: sender.title)

    }
}
```

This event is then handled by an UI element in `ContentView`.

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack(){
       ...
    }.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: Notification.Name.handleKeyboardShortcut)) { notification in
            if let shortcutKey = notification.object as? String {
                switch shortcutKey {
                case "New File":
                    self.openNewFile()
                case "Show Panel":
                    self.openConsolePanel()
                ...
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
}
```

Then the problem arises, when pressing `Command + N` while running 2 scenes of the app side-by-side, both scenes' `openNewFile` function is fired. Both instances pop up an file selection sheet. This is obviously an undesirable behavior.

[image: Multiple sheets popped up]

I have a few ideas regarding the issue.

1. Check if the scene is last interacted, and only call the function `openNewFile` if so.
2. Handle `UIKeyCommands` outside `HostingController`, since it's shared by all scenes. In particular, I want to use  `addKeyCommand(_:)` equivalent methods inside `ContentView` so that the UIKeyCommands can be dynamically changed.

I don't quite know how implement these though. What could be the best way to handle the problem?

Comment: They are not two instances of app, but two scenes of one app instance. Just use your NotificationCenter observer not in views, which are two in your case, but in AppDelegate, which is always one.

Comment: @Asperi Thanks for clarifying! In that way, I'll have to identify which scene is active, or last interacted and call the corresponding method in it. Any chance you could provide an example for that?